# Java, generate random polygons in desired locations

Tags: java, math, polygon

I need to generate random polygons to use as asteroids for my game. I've been experimenting, trying to figure out how to do this but I keep getting stuck finding the x and y positions.

To start, I create an angle and a length for each point of the polygon. The length depends on the randomly generated size for the asteroid.

```
    asteroidData = new double[10][2];

    for (int i = 0; i < asteroidData.length; i++) {
        //angle
        asteroidData[i][0] = Math.random()*2*Math.PI;

        //length
        asteroidData[i][1] = sze + Math.random()*sze/2; 
    }
```

and then since g.fillPolygon requires the points to be sorted according to angle I did this..

```
    Arrays.sort(asteroidData, new Comparator<double[]>() {
       @Override
       public int compare(final double[] entry1, final double[] entry2) {
           if (entry1[0] == entry2[0])
               return 0;
           if (entry1[0] > entry2[0])
                return 1;
           return -1;
       }
    });
```

I'm just a little loss on the math for creating the final point itself/figuring out the coordinates for the point. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Okay I've figured a little more out, using trig I can find the length and the width of the point using ratios. But does anyone know which ratios I should be using? as well, how to differ which quadrant the point is in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the length you're generating is the distance from the origin of the asteroid and not the length of the side, then the following should give you the (x,y) coordinates of an entry.

```
// ...
double angle = entry[0];
double length = entry[1];
double x = Math.cos(angle) * length;
double y = Math.sin(angle) * length;
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about simple polygons, you need to make sure that the following invariant is satisfied: d = 180(n-2), where d is the number of degrees and n is the number of sides. For example, a triangle has 180 degrees, since d = 180(3-2) = 180(1) = 180.

Alternatively, you could just calculate k points with random x,y coordinates and just connect them to get a k sided polygon. Trying to calculate side lengths and angles seems a bit overzealous.